# Ultra low noise power supply ( 2 output 2.5 V and -2.5 V)

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design

I am designing an extremely low noise source with an input of V = 3.5V
The goal of the circuit is 2 outputs with voltages of 2.5V and - 2.5 V.
So I would like to ask when designing a power circuit like this, what parameters should we pay attention to and how to determine them.
For example, I know I have to use an LDO with a high PSRR value, but how high is enough to determine. Besides, the PSRR value depends on one situation with particular Vin, Vout, and Iout and change if we change the condition, so how to make a decision when comes to design?

I'm just starting to learn about power circuit design, so I hope everyone can help me. Thank you everyone very much

**Update:**
I'm very sorry everyone, after I asked my teacher for more information, I would like to add the following information
To create a voltage from 3.5 V -> 2.5 V, my teacher suggested using LDO
From 3.5 V -> -2.5 V, it can be designed as follows: 3.5V -> charge pump,.. -> LDO -> -2.5V

According to the drawing I gave you, I will have to supply power to the OPA2376AIDR opam as well as the ADC and at the same time make a reference voltage for it. I have tried to refer to the datasheet of these two components but I still don't understand. It's very clear what the maximum output current parameter is.

Regarding noise, the teacher requires that the Output noise voltage be as low as possible (there is no specific requirement for this parameter).
But I added one more condition: Dropout voltage < 100 mV

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me.[image]

Comment: An LDO cannot generate -2.5V from 3.5V; you need a SMPS. Making this low-noise will be more of a challenge than an LDO.

Comment: We need more information.  What is the max output current for each output?  Also, what are the noise parameters you need to meet or exceed?  "extremely" tells us nothing.  As above, you will have to have some form of energy storage and transfer mechanism to create a negative output potential from a positive input.  This can be a flyback topology (sometimes called a buck regulator or inverting buck regulator), a charge pump, a sinewave oscillator and transformer, etc.  Whatever it is, it will need lots of output capacitors.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I just have updated my information to my question.

Comment: Editing posts is for keeping posts clear, relevant, and up-to-date. StackExchange already keeps an [edit history for each post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/687849/revisions): marking parts of a post the result of an edit compromises clarity.

Comment: The teacher's request is not justified; "as low as possible" requires cryogenic and superconducting equipment, and achieves some nanovolts of noise at modest bandwidths. I'm guessing this is not intended, being beyond the scope of most student budgets, so, they should be more specific. Alternately, you've misinterpreted the requirement for noise at the ADC input, with respect to op-amp PSRR, which is a much more relaxed figure. Even then, the ADC is only sensitive to noise within a bandwidth, and rejects high frequencies, so "lowest possible" is still a dubious claim.

Comment: Noise has to be quantified including bandwidth. If you consider 20 MHz BW, an LDO would a terrible choice and passive filters would do much better. It can be that you will need both an LDO and filters. Power supply impedance is equally important to PSRR. There vote to close.

Comment: Also dropout below 100 mV is hard to achieve if you **have to drop** 1 Volt from 3.5 V to 2.5 V.

Answer (score 1):

> Regarding noise, the teacher requires that the Output noise voltage be as low as possible (there is no specific requirement for this parameter).

If you don't have a requirement then it's not possible to do, so the first thing is to check what kind of "low noise" you need on that power supply.

An important thing to remember is that it's possible to make a "low noise" voltage... as long as you're only drawing a constant current from it. If a dynamic variable current is drawn from it, then due to the output impedance of the circuit not being zero, there will be voltage ripple depending on output current. This is usually way higher than the noise spec, making it irrelevant.

A typical example is audiophiles using µV "low noise" power supplies for opamps. Opamp draws variable current, even 1mA over 1mOhm of power supply wiring will create a variable voltage drop of more than 1µV. So the extra cost of "low noise" is not money well spent in this case.

So the first thing to do is check the noise spec of your ADC chip. I'm not going to read all the datasheet, but I see "Input-Referred Noise: 1 μVPP (70-Hz BW)" on the front page so let's go with that. Next it has a PSRR spec:

[image]

Let's go with the worse case of 80dB which is 10000 ; in this case 10000µV noise on the power supply will result in 1µV equivalent noise added to the input. So to be safe we can go with 1mV noise in the bandwidth of interest (1-70Hz). Current draw should be around 7mA plus patient bias plus U3 opamp, so let's go with "a couple tens of mA".

It seems it's designed to be connected to the patient directly without opamps in between so there's no more datasheet PSRR to look at.

**Unfortunately** the datasheet doesn't say how variable the supply current is. Maybe you can measure it. For example if the chip draws 3mA variable current then to have 1mV ripple we need the LDO to have an output impedance below 0.3 ohms, which they pretty much all do.

I looked at the [evaluation module datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau443b/slau443b.pdf) which has schematics, but no power supply. It is powered by the mainboard it is mounted on. Here are its [schematics](https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/73/1121.MMB0_5F00_Sch_5F00_RevD.PDF). For 5V it uses a [REG104](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/reg104.pdf) which is a bit obsolete and very expensive, it specs 33µV noise and about 25mOhm output impedance. But on this board the 5V rail also powers other LDOs that power a big CPU so it's not especially "low noise" either.

Anyway.

For the negative supply I'd use an inverting charge pump powered from +3.5V, delivering noisy -3.5V. Then a LC filter (ferrite bead plus cap, make sure it doesn't ring) to remove high frequency noise from the charge pump, and a -2.5V LDO. These are hard to find, but [TPS72325](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps723.pdf) should do the trick.

The PSRR of a LDO depends on dropout. Look at what dropout voltage it is specified in the datasheet. If you operate it close to its minimum dropout voltage then it will have no PSRR. That's why I'm going with inverting -3.5 then 1V headroom for the LDO. And since LDO PSRR drops at high frequency it's a good match with a LC filter whose rejection increases with frequency. The filter should go on the input in order to preserve a low output impedance.

For the positive supply I'd put a LC filter before a +2.5V LDO, the main problem with these is having too many options to choose from. Lowish noise (but not super low), high-ish PSRR in case the main supply is contaminated by noise from your CPU, decent low output impedance... Here's [an example](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp115-d.pdf). One of my pet selection criteria is that the transient response graph X axis should be in µs and not ms, and the transient response should look good, well damped.

As far as capacitors are concerned, check the LDO datasheets for minimum values. If it doesn't say anything about maximum capacitance you can use more, you'll get better transient response.

Now the most important node regarding noise for your ADC is its reference voltage because what an ADC does is output a digital value which is the ratio of input voltage and reference voltage. If VREF is noisy, it's just as bad as noise on the input. If you use the internal reference and buffer, you avoid an opportunity of screwing it up.

Comment: The self-impedance part is not quite true; or disingenuous -- for audio for example, supply error in response to signal current, merely causes an extremely small gain or frequency-response error due to Iload * Zsupply * PSRR. If gain needs to be extremely precise, this might be a kind of "noise", but wouldn't usually be called "signal noise" (uncorrelated signal superimposed on desired/input signal). The rest is spot on. Note that charge pumps can be quite noisy (input and output!), and at middle frequencies (10s kHz); make sure to choose LDO and filter to accommodate this.

Comment: (The same reasoning applied to an ADC specifically, it's not obvious to me what current one might draw. Presumably it will be data-dependent, so, varying erratically with input; and digital currents won't be so well correlated with the input signal, so could be considered "noisy", though it will also be predominantly at fractional-clock-rate frequencies. Though given that the PSRR doesn't show much rise by even 1kHz, I'm actually a bit suspicious of how fast it rolls off, if it at all(!). But that should largely be in the VDD not VDDA pins, and VDDA is hopefully just amps and switches? Dunno.)

Comment: Hmm yes I see what you mean, but consider multiple uncorrelated channels: what ripple on the supply due to one channel does to the other channels isn't exactly "noise" as we usually mean it, but my point is that if there's enough of it, there's not much point in investing in a low noise supply to begin with.

Comment: I've measured supply current on a few sigma delta ADCs, found mostly HF noise that averages to rather constant DC not dependent on signal. I guess it's due to 1) modulator scrambling the data and 2) internal differential structure which keeps supply current independent of input signal. I suspect ADC designers would try to avoid creating ripple on the chip's internal supply.